# Couchbase Microservice Architecture

Tags: couchbase, microservices, couchbase-sync-gateway

I've read a lot of articles about having a datastore per microservice. I'm going to use this approach but want to know the best way to go about it using Couchbase Sync Gateway since I want to use Sync Gateway REST API calls both from mobile AND backend server apps. I am thinking that the simplest way to go about this is to have one Couchbase cluster (3-n Couchbase Server instances) with maybe 2-3 buckets. A bucket for sessions maybe, another for all of my data, and maybe some others later. For each microservice's "database", instead of having different physical clusters for each, I'm thinking I should just put all of the data in one bucket and differentiate the databases and tables by document fields. So maybe I would have something like:

```
{
  database: 'person-api'
  doc_type: 'Person'

  ...
}
```

I would also have multiple database entries for each service all pointing to the same bucket in my sync-gateway config file. Then I would need to set up ACLs or some kind of controls that would only allow the backend server applications to access their own databases (so the 'election-api' server could only read/write docs with the corresponding `database` property). This would all have to be through Sync Gateway, for writes at least (I might do most reads using the sdks instead).

Sync Gateway is still a bit confusing to me and I'm not sure if this is the best approach. Would I just use channels as a sort of ACL? Is this just a bad approach to begin with? Any suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score -1):

So in Sync Gateway you have the concept of CHANNELS , JSON Docs & USERS.

In the micro service model you probably want to separate data into different parts when:

- You want to use a specific sub-set of data in the future for other
  projects.
- You may want that data to have a sync function for a
  specific  purpose.
- You might want to keep things simple and you do not want to manage a very large and
  complicated sync function to manage all the data types.
- You have very specific security concerns. So have one sync gateway database
  for public information and a second one for very private/sensitive
  data.